# Caulking Baseboards - Suddenly Spiders Appear

Tags: caulk, pest

We recently moved into our first home, and the previous owner had done some self-installed laminate floors to replace carpet. This left about 1/16" gap between the baseboard trim and floor.

We started to caulk between the baseboard and the floor to seal it all up, and we're about 30% done. Within 8 hours, we've found 5 spiders (Harmless house spiders) in the hallways that have been caulked!

Is this a new pest problem, or were these spiders likely always around, but we've sealed up their hunting paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocking their hiding spaces and places with air flow probably displaced them. With the area sealed up they won’t have food traveling that area so they are probably getting away from the smell and looking for new places to reside.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I'll share this with my Wife who was understandably freaked out. Last night I heard her exclaim "Oh my God!!! Why are there so many??!?". . . Though telling her they've probably always been here might not be a great comfort.

Comment: @Aww_Geez  not the time to show her your Spider man costume..+ for Ed's answer.

Comment: Obviously he used the brand of caulk that contains spider food material.   Wait until these spiders tell the other spiders nearby.   Spider buffet!